# The constructor PlainTextByLineStream(StringReader) is undefined

Tags: java, opennlp

any idea why it's happening, i'm using java version 10.0.1

```
public void POSTag() throws IOException {
        POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("lib/en-pos-maxent.bin"));
        PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
        POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);
    String input = "Hi. How are you? This is Mike.";
    ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(new StringReader(input));
    perfMon.start();
    String line;
    while ((line = lineStream.read()) != null) {

        String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE
                .tokenize(line);
        String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);

        POSSample sample = new POSSample(whitespaceTokenizerLine, tags);
        System.out.println(sample.toString());

        perfMon.incrementCounter();
    }
    perfMon.stopAndPrintFinalResult();
}
```

while compiling the above program i'm getting and error
like so

> The constructor PlainTextByLineStream(StringReader) is undefined.

What is the cause of the message and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Did you check my answer? Did it help you in solving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official OpenNLP JavaDoc of the class [PlainTextByLineStream](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.4/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/util/PlainTextByLineStream.html) two constructors exist.

1. `PlainTextByLineStream(InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory, Charset charset)`
2. `PlainTextByLineStream(InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory, String charsetName)`

As can be seen, there is **no** constructor such as `PlainTextByLineStream(StringReader reader)`.

However, in your code, you can use one of the existing constructors as follows:

```
// ...
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
InputStreamFactory isf = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(new File("myText.txt"));
ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(isf, charset);
// ...
while ((line = lineStream.read()) != null) {
   // process
}
```

Note well that you have to provide a reference to a `File` (here: "mytext.txt") supplying the text content.

Hope it helps.